# pivot in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to put the result set in pivot in SQL Developer but it looks like the query is incorrect. could you suggest correct query to see data in pivot.

```
select * 
from(select b.create_date,a.system_serial_number,a.system_status,b.pathway_id,b.ref_trans_id,
            row_number() over (partition by b.system_serial_number 
                               order by b.ref_trans_id,b.create_date desc ) R 
              from eim.eim_pr_system a, eim.eim_pr_system_pathway b 
              where a.system_serial_number=b.system_serial_number 
                and a.system_serial_number not in (select system_serial_number 
                                                   from eim.eim_pr_ib_latest 
                                                   where role_id = 1 
                                                       and cmat_customer_id <> -999999)
              )
where R=1
pivot (count(system_serial_number) as cnts for (system_status) 
    in ('ACTIVE' as active,'INACTIVE' as inactive,'DECOMISSIONED' as DECOMISSIONED))
```

data:

```
create_date system_serial_number    system_status   pathway_id  ref_trans_id    r
18-Feb-16   2018514                 ACTIVE          22          8000646123  1
18-Feb-16   20020615                ACTIVE          22          8000593745  1
18-Feb-16   30009010                ACTIVE          22          8000535738  1
18-Feb-16   30016030                inACTIVE        22          8000594796  1
18-Feb-16   30016718                ACTIVE          20          733187      1
18-Feb-16   30016814                inACTIVE        22          8000515760  1
18-Feb-16   3.0054E+12              ACTIVE          22          8000534021  1
18-Feb-16   3012504                 ACTIVE          22          8000432757  1
```

currently i m doing this in excel..exporting and pivoting in excel
.
the expected result in sql i need is

```
             Column Labels
             Sum of system_serial_number    
Row Labels   20                           22            Grand Total
ACTIVE       30016718                     3.00546E+12   3.00549E+12
inACTIVE                                  60032844      60032844
Grand Total  30016718                     3.00552E+12   3.00555E+12
```

Comment: Can you try and format your query, and data? Almost impossible to read it as it is now.

Comment: @jarlh I think is almost readeable now.

Comment: @FlorinGhita, at least it's much better. (I find it hard to read code if I have to scroll side-ways...)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to see if that's the result you're trying to get (notice the differences in the `PIVOT` clause):

```
SELECT
  system_status "Row Labels",
  twenty_cnts "20",
  twentytwo_cnts "22",
  (nvl(twenty_cnts,0) + nvl(twentytwo_cnts,0)) "Grand Total"
FROM (
  SELECT
    system_serial_number,
    system_status,
    pathway_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      B.create_date,
      A.system_serial_number,
      A.system_status,
      B.pathway_id,
      B.ref_trans_id,
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY B.system_serial_number
                        ORDER BY B.ref_trans_id, B.create_date DESC) R 
    FROM
      eim.eim_pr_system A,
      eim.eim_pr_system_pathway B
    WHERE
      A.system_serial_number = B.system_serial_number 
      AND a.system_serial_number NOT IN (SELECT
                                          system_serial_number 
                                        FROM
                                          eim.eim_pr_ib_latest 
                                        WHERE
                                          role_id = 1 
                                          AND cmat_customer_id <> -999999)
  )
  WHERE
    R = 1
)
PIVOT (SUM(system_serial_number) as cnts
      FOR (pathway_id) in ('20' twenty, '22' twentytwo)
)
```